# Batch file: write to file >> was unexpect at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am using `for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~ni >> C:\dev\BO-lists\_file.txt` to list all files in a directory. This works great from command line, however, it says this error when run from `.bat` file.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loops in batch files needs escaping the percent signs to avoid expansion. Quoting `for /?`:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.

So do it with two percent signs like this:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do @echo %%~ni >> C:\dev\BO-lists\_file.txt
```

Comment: This is really stupid error. Worst part on it is that the `>>` wasn't even wrong at all. Thanks!